# iphone sdk+How to retrive dictionary inside array of dictionary values

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

i want to retrive KpiName key(KpiData is array inside kpiName is dictionary key) and my data structure mentioned below

```
--Array of dictionaries inside array of dictinary
ex..listOfProjectsArray--(
        {
        alertSeverity = 1;
        customerName = TPMG;
        endDate = "05-05-2013";
        isProjectHide = 1;
        kpiData =         (
                        {
                KpiName = "Change Request ";
                kpiActual = 14;
                kpiPlanned = "";
                kpiUnit = "";
            },
                        {
                KpiName = "Aged Debit";
                kpiActual = 24000;
                kpiPlanned = "";
                kpiUnit = EUR;
            },
        );
        lastInvoiceDate = "05-04-2013";
        nextBillingDate = "05-04-2013";
        nextMilestoneDate = "10-04-2013";
        nextReviewDate = "08-04-2013";
        plannedCompletionDate = "04-05-2013";
        projectID = 3000;
        projectName = "Rain Harvesting";
        projectSortType = "";
        projectStatus = 1;
        startDate = "01-01-2013";
    },
```

i tried this one but its returning null

```
   NSString *kpiName = [[[[listOfProjectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"kpiData"] objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"kpiName"];
       NSLog(@"kpiname:%@", kpiName);
```

Comment: Keys are case sensitive. Try KpiName instead of kpiName

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    NSString *kpiName =[[[[listOfProjectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"kpiData"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"KpiName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was mentioned wrong dictionary key

```
NSString *kpiName = [[[[listOfProjectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"kpiData"] objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"kpiName"];
       NSLog(@"kpiname:%@", kpiName);
```

correct  one is `KpiName` key instead of `kpiName`.